# What is the best way to get erfi with scipy?

Tags: python

I want this:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

But apparently scipy does not have this in its extensive special functions library.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html

It is not the same as erfinv.  Right now I am using an obscure identity involving the hyp1f1 hypergeometric function but I would rather use a nicer function if possible.  Also I'll pre-emptively say that I would rather not deal with complex numbers, because the inputs and outputs are all real.

Comment: How about np.real(-1j * sp.special.erf(1j * x))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erfi is available from the mpmath library.

See documentation here:
http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/expintegrals.html#mpmath.erfi

Here is a link to the library:
https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this because it is a good answer and I didn't mention mpmath in my question.  I would still be interested to see a better scipy hack.

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer in SciPy is given by datageist in his comment:

(-1.0j)*scipy.special.erf((-1.0j*x))

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, in SciPy 0.11 or earlier, the erf function is [rather inaccurate](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/1207) for complex arguments.  However, SciPy 0.12 will contain accurate complex erf support and includes an [optimized erfi function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfi.html).   Alternatively, you can use the `scipy.special.dawsn` function, which computes the Dawson function, a scaled erfi function.  erfi(x) is then given by (2/sqrt(pi)) * exp(x^2) * dawsn(x).